# Assigning to an environment in R

Tags: r, variable-assignment, evaluation, expression-evaluation

The code:

```
env <- new.env()
assign("X", value = 2,  pos = env)
eval(X, envir = env)
```

Results in an error: "X not found"

However:

```
ls(envir = env)
```

returns "X"

Why doesn't the eval return 2?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work:

```
eval(quote(X),envir=env)
```

Problem is it tries to evaluate X and then pass it to `eval` but X has no value in your main environment so it gives an error. Putting `quote` tells eval to look for `X` in `env`

Comment: technically, `quote(X)` tells `eval` *not to look for `X` yet* (i.e. in the current environment); `envir=env` is what tells it to look in `env`, once it gets around to looking ...

Comment: You can also use `evalq(X,envir=env)` as a "shortcut" for the quoting

Comment: If this works (and it does) why doesn't eval("X", envir=env) work (and it doesn't)? 

    quote(xx) == "xx"
    [1] TRUE

Comment: "X" is a string and will return the string back when you evaluate. Quote says simply take object X and don't evaluate. Then you evaluate it with eval in a specific environment